# On Row Command for GridView control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView control in my C# web application.  In my gridview I have a ButtonField called Select, `ID="btnSelect"`.  Basically in my GridView control, I have a clients firstname, last name, addr, and phone number, and for the for the corresponding information I have textboxes.  When I hit/ fire the select button in the gridview, I want the clients name to go into the text box, and I have done that successfully, however in my application you can select up to 6 clients.  Is there a better way than how I am doing this?  Code is below:

```
 void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
  int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
  GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];


  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName1.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLName1.Text) &&
     string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddr1.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPhone1.Text))
    {
      txtName1.Text=Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[1].Text);
      txtLName1.Text=Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[2].Text);
      txtAddr1.Text=Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[3].Text);
      txtPhone1.Text=Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[4].Text);

    }
  //If I hit another select button then this will load the sencond set of txtboxes
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName2.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLName2.Text) &&
     string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddr2.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPhone2.Text))
    {
      txtName2.Text=Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[1].Text);
      txtLName2.Text=Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[2].Text);
      txtAddr2.Text=Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[3].Text);
      txtPhone2.Text=Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[4].Text);

    }
 //The thrid time will load the third button and so on until I fill each txtbox if I choose.
}
```

Is there a better way to code this to where if each time I hit the Select button in the row Command, I will not have to put all those complicated if statements there?  Is there like a foreach loop that can handle this  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at the FindControl Method.

You could use the following:

```
TextBox txtName = FindControl(string.Format("txtName{0}", index) as TextBox;
if(txtName != null)
{
txtName.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

Comment: It will work for any control on the page. (not within another control). You just have to change "txtName" for "txtAddr", "txtPhone" etc etc. My code assumes a button per row. so, row of button clicked matches row of txt boxes

Answer (score 0):

An optimised version is here

```
void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
    GridViewRow row = ((Control) sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    PopulateClients(txtName1, txtLName1, txtAddr1, txtPhone1, row);

    //If I hit another select button then this will load the sencond set of txtboxes
    PopulateClients(txtName2, txtLName2, txtAddr2, txtPhone2, row);
    //The thrid time will load the third button and so on until I fill each txtbox if I choose.
}

private void PopulateClients(TextBox t1, TextBox t2, TextBox t3, TextBox t4, GridViewRow r) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(t1.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(t2.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(t3.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(t4.Text)) {
        t1.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(r.Cells[1].Text);
        t2.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(r.Cells[2].Text);
        t3.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(r.Cells[3].Text);
        t4.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(r.Cells[4].Text);    
    }
}​
```

Comment: This is great, I am tweeking it now because it says that my  t1.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(r.Cells[1].Text); is not set to new instance of object or check to determine if object is null.  It looks like all I have to do is find the right index and put that in the  populateclients.  Btw, how did you get your sub to work?

Comment: where or what are you passing as your row index

Comment: the first line of the code gives the gridviewrow. no need to pass DisplayIndex as CommandArgument and get the gris

Comment: Oh, I see, you are passing the GridViewCommandEventArgs, ok I was a little confused but you cleared that up. Thanks and your code works awesome!

Comment: but at first I was using int index= Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) then GridviewRow row= Gridview1.Rows[index];, that is what I was using first!

Comment: The button is inside the gridview.